# Mobile keyboard in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am implementing unity login screen in my android game. The problem is that when I click on the InputField, the keyboard opens in floating mode:
[image: Floating Mode]

I attached the following method to the InputField:

```
public void onTouch()
    {
        TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput = true;
        TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default);          
    }
```

I've tried various variations of the overloaded **Open** method and keyboard types. It opened different types of keyboard, but didn't remove the floating mode.

Of course, I can manually disable this mode on the keyboard itself, and then it will always start up normally. But this problem is on all smartphones with Android 12 at the first start. And I would like the keyboard to start up normally right away.

Also, this line

```
TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput = true;
```

should disable the keyboard's own input field. However, she does not. I looked at Android Logcat, and found out that after opening the keyboard, this field becomes **False**.

I know that I can implement my own keyboard inside Unity. And I will resort to this method if I don't find another solution.

How can I disable floating mode? And how can I disable the keyboard input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote almost same script as you, but everything is working fine, first thing that you mentioned is keyboard opening in floating mode.

Right now i did build android game and the same script as yours opening default keyboard attached to the bottom of screen(as it should be), probably it's your problem, maybe you changed it in phone settings or somewhere else, but still there's unnecessary input field, i managed to remove it after short delay, like this:

```
public void openAndroidKeyboard()
{
    TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default);
    Invoke("hideInputField", 0.1f);
}
private void hideInputField()
{
    TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput = true;
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way to disable it, but it works, you can try less delay to make it less noticable,

Comment: Do you have android 12?

Comment: i got android 11

Comment: Therefore, everything is displayed normally for you, I know that this problem is only on Android 12.

Comment: I understand you, but how you could fix it from unity, if it is android problem as you said.

Comment: Obviously there's exists some kind of fix it, but still it will work bad, i guess best decision is to make own keyboard.

Comment: No, I meant that this problem is only on android 12, and it is not on version 10 or 11. I think that Unity can send a command to the operating system to display the keyboard normally. I can also implement my own keyboard in Unity to solve this problem, but this is a bad solution, because we should stick to the standard solutions already implemented in Unity.

Comment: I checked your solution about hiding the keyboard input field. It worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried it on more than one android 12 device, at least 3 devices?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it on 3 android 12 devices and on 1 android 10 device. I didn't have the problem on android 10.

Comment: I advise you to check your application for 12 android

Comment: [here my friend tried on android 12](https://ibb.co/17b3pmQ)
[also here](https://ibb.co/yVFkbs9)

Comment: Анекдот: встретились как-то двое русских на стековерфлоу...
Ok, thanks for the info, so my sample was not representative